# Appropriate way to group static functions in python

Tags: python, oop, static

What is the appropriate way to group together static functions in Python?

Considerations:

1. Functions in the same group do not need to share a state or any information.
2. There are several groups each containing 3 functions, all sharing a common "interface".

It seems like the solution would be creating a class for each group. This has the advantage of easily providing an interface by subclassing an abstract class. Also this is less messy then creating separate modules for groups. However, it makes no sense to instantiate these classes - they should really be static classes.

Any ideas what is the best way of designing this? Should I add @staticmethod to each method in each class or is there a more elegant way of doing it (e.g. declaring the whole class static)?

**EDIT:** Since the question was tagged as "opinion-based", I will ask more concretely: Is there anyway to declare a whole class static?

Comment: Do you actually need to use inheritance? If not, why not just use module-level functions rather than static methods?

Comment: @ErikAllik I considered this. The downsides are that I have many groups, so that would mean creating a module for each group (3-4 functions) which is a bit messy I think. Also the groups follow the same template ("interface") and could potentially even share a method, so it makes sense in terms of design to use inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to declare a whole class static?

You can use a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=metaclass#customizing-class-creation) to achieve this. That way you can intercept the class-creation and replace all methods by static methods.

```
from types import FunctionType


class StaticMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        def transform(f):
            if type(f) == FunctionType:
                return staticmethod(f)
            return f

        newdct = dict((k, transform(v)) for k, v in dct.iteritems())

        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, newdct)


class StaticBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = StaticMetaClass


class Static(StaticBase):
    def func1():
        print "func1"

    def func2(a, b):
        print "func2", a, b


Static.func1()
Static.func2(1, "World")
```

> [...] is there a more elegant way of doing it [...] ?

I will leave the question, whether this is more elegant, to you. However, the usage of metaclasses is generally discouraged, if it is avoidable. They tend to make code bases much more complicated and confusing. Also, many programmers are not very familiar with them. So, your code will become harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks - that's a nice trick. I am surprised there isn't a simpler way of achieving what I want (I've got used to almost everything being easy and neat in Python).

Comment: @Bitwise The reason why this is so complicated is the way that staticmethods work. As I understand the docs: The builtin function `staticmethod` returns a `staticmethod` object. When the corresponding class is created `type` scans it for `staticmethod` members and places a descriptor in the right place in the class. That descriptor will return the wrapped function as a free function upon call to `__get__`. A pure python implementation of staticmethod is given [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods).